# Verify user through PayPal GetVerifiedStatus API

Tags: api, authentication, paypal

I have been trying to get this GetVerifiedStatus API to work but it just doesn't work.

I have tried using a valid email address on 
http://www.dev-tool.com/pptester/NVP/CallType.aspx?ServiceID=51&CallTypeID=53
As well as directly and through curl but they all give error of 'Api credentials are incorrect'.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Then I have another question, paypal says that [GetVerifiedStatus API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getverifiedstatus-api-operation) takes in email,first name and last name. (as mentioned in )

However there is this [guy](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/signature-sandbox-and-live) who says that he verified using email, password and signature successfully... anybody has any idea where do password and signature comes in it from?

Thanks

Comment: You can refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228963/how-to-validate-paypal-account/3273658#3273658
This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The link you're referring to is talking about an API username, password and signature.

To use GetVerifiedStatus, you **must** send email, firstName, lastName and matchCriteria.
See also page 63 of https://www.paypal-biz.com/development/documentation/PP_AdaptiveAccounts.pdf

Comment: The document doesn't help either... isn't there anywhere they give an example url with some test account?
I have tried with giving API username,signature and password but that gives the same error of 'API credentials are incorrect'

Answer (score 0):

To use GetVerifiedStatus.php here is what you have to do:

1. Create an account [paypal sandboc](https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_certs-session)
2. Create a preconfigured account
3. Click on API and Payment Card Credentials to view your account credentials
4. Update the following code with the credentials you got from step 3

   ```
   //PayPal API Credentials
   $API_UserName = "sbapi_1287090601_biz_api1.paypal.com"; //TODO
   $API_Password = "1287090610"; //TODO
   $API_Signature = "ANFgtzcGWolmjcm5vfrf07xVQ6B9AsoDvVryVxEQqezY85hChCfdBMvY"; //TODO

   //PAYPAL SANDBOX LOGIN EMAIL
   $API_SANDBOX_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "rishaque@paypal.com"; <<<<< THIS IS YOUR LOGIN EMAIL ADDRESS
   ```

I hope this help.